# Wrong SQL query generated by Doctrine2 Paginator

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

My scripts stop working after I've upgraded from Doctrine 2.3.6 up to Doctrine 2.5.0 .

I want to perform query with pagination on joined tables. I have two entities: `Program` and `ProgramVersion` joined by `Program::versions` field. 
Here is the query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
SELECT m, v 
FROM Entity\Program m 
LEFT JOIN m.versions v 
WITH m.version = v.version 
WHERE m.deletedDate IS NULL 
ORDER BY m.type asc');
```

Then I pass the query to `Paginator`

```
$pResult = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator($query, true);
```

At the stage when I do `$pResult->getIterator()` I get the following error message:

```
An exception occurred while executing '

SELECT DISTINCT id_0 
FROM (
    SELECT e0_.id AS id_0, e1_.id AS id_27 /* removed a lot of fields here */ FROM entity_program e0_ 
    LEFT JOIN entity_program_version e1_ ON e0_.id = e1_.master_id AND (e0_.version = e1_.version) 
    WHERE e0_.deleted_date IS NULL
) dctrn_result ORDER BY e0_.type_id ASC':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e0_.type_id' in 'order clause'
```

Obviously the SQL is wrong. The `ORDER BY` clause is outside of the main `SELECT` and it contains the field which doesn't exist.

Can anybody help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Looks like it is a Doctrine bug. I've reverted to 2.4.7 and it is working ok. Will open issue in Doctrine's bugtracker.